# warning occurs in c for struct using callback function

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct complex {
    int real;
    int imag;

} complex;
complex n1, n2;
complex add(complex n1, complex n2) {
    complex temp;
    temp.real = n1.real + n2.real;
    temp.imag = n1.imag + n2.imag;
    printf("%d+%di",temp.real,temp.imag);
    return (temp);
  
}
complex sub(complex n1,complex n2)
{
    complex temp;
    temp.real = n1.real - n2.real;
    temp.imag = n1.imag - n2.imag;
    printf("%d+%di",temp.real,temp.imag);
    return (temp);
  
}
complex mul(complex n1,complex n2)
{
    complex temp;
    temp.real = (n1.real * n2.real)-(n1.imag * n2.imag);
    temp.imag = (n1.real*n2.imag)+(n1.imag * n2.real);
    printf("%d+%di",temp.real,temp.imag);
    return (temp);
  
}
void c(complex n1,complex n2,void(*ptr)(complex,complex))
{
  (*ptr)(n1,n2);
}
int main() 
{
  
  int choice;
  printf("For 1st complex number \n");
  printf("Enter the real and imaginary parts: ");
  scanf("%d %d", &n1.real, &n1.imag);
  printf("\nFor 2nd complex number \n");
  printf("Enter the real and imaginary parts: ");
  scanf("%d %d", &n2.real, &n2.imag);
  printf("which operation  can do:");
  scanf("%d",&choice);
  switch(choice)
  {
    case 1:
    c(n1,n2,&add);
    break;
    case 2:
    c(n1,n2,&sub);
    break;
    case 3:
    c(n1,n2,&mul);
    break;
    default:
    printf("bye enter the choice btw 1-3");
    break;
  }
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is the warning from the compiler:

```
warning: incompatible function pointer types passing 'complex (*)(complex, complex)' 
(aka 'struct complex (*)(struct complex, struct complex)') to parameter of type 
'void (*)(complex, complex)' (aka 'void (*)(struct complex, struct complex)')
[-Wincompatible-function-pointer-types]
```

Comment: The message means that your arguments do not match what is specified in parameter list: Change `void c(complex n1, complex n2, void(*ptr)(complex,complex))` => `void c(complex n1, complex n2, complex(*ptr)(complex,complex))`. Or change the functions `add`, `sub`, `mul` to have `void` return type.

Comment: Side note: C already has `_Complex` type

Comment: void c(complex n1,complex n2,void(*ptr)(complex,complex)) it can be changed to void c(complex n1,complex n2,complex(*ptr)(complex,complex))

Comment: Stop torturing yourself and use typedefs. `typedef complex complex_func_t  (complex,complex)` then `void c(complex n1,complex n2, complex_func_t* func)`

Answer (score 3):

#### Meaning of the warning

The warning message is actually pretty straight forward:

It means the function that receives your **complex-function-pointer** here:

```c
void c(complex n1,complex n2,void(*ptr)(complex,complex))
{
  (*ptr)(n1,n2);
}
```

does not accept function-pointers of type `complex(*)(complex, complex)` but of type `void(*)(complex, complex)`. So it expects a pointer to a function that returns nothing (`void`) but it gets a function pointer to a function that returns `complex`.

Also have a look at a bit more insight into function pointers and their meanings here: [How do function pointers in C work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work?rq=1)

#### Solution

You have two options to change your program:

Either you change the argument to your function that receives the function pointers from `void(*ptr) ...` to `complex(*ptr) ...` (Option 2 below) or you change the signature of the functions that are used from `complex(*ptr) ...` to `void(*ptr) ...` (Option 1 below).

**Option 1 (Preferred): Change all producers** (functions you are pointing to)

For all complex-number functions change the implementations analogously to this:

```c
void add(complex n1, complex n2) {
    complex temp;
    temp.real = n1.real + n2.real;
    temp.imag = n1.imag + n2.imag;
    printf("%d+%di",temp.real,temp.imag);

    // omitting the return-value here
    // you could also explicitly return like so:
    // return;
}
```

In my opinion this is the preferred solution, because right now you don't use the return value of the functions.

**Option 2: Change consumer** (receiver of function pointer)

```c
void c(complex n1,complex n2,complex(*ptr)(complex,complex))
{
  (*ptr)(n1,n2);
}
```

#### Background

Just to clarify the meaning of the function-pointer-notion:

`void(*ptr)(complex, complex)` is referring to a function-pointer named `ptr`, that points to a function which receives two values of type `complex` and returns `void` (nothing).

`complex(*ptr)(complex, complex)` is referring to a function-pointer named `ptr`, that points to a function which receives two values of type `complex` and returns a value of type `complex`.